# parsem array of string data into json

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I have a folder of .TXT extensions file with plain text in it how can I insert that plain text into the MongoDB database using the mongoose and fs module in node js

```
const fs = require('fs');
var parsedata;
var parsedTwice = [];
let fileName;
fs.readdir("D:/scnner_data/public", (err, data) => {
    if(err) throw err
    console.log(data);
    fileName = data;
    console.log(fileName);
});

fs.readFile('D:/scnner_data/public/DC221020042103SC.TXT',"utf8", (err,  data) =>{
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
         parsedata = data.split("\n");
         for(let item of parsedata) {
            parsedTwice.push(item.split(";"));
         }
        //console.log('successful' , parsedTwice);
        // console.log('this line is being readed' + parsedata);
    }
}
)
```

Comment: What do you want your document(s) to look like?  I.e., what is your database data model?

Comment: we have data there is 6 TH and there are thousands of TD so we require the file using the FS module and we could convert it into JSON?

Comment: Would you show what an example document looks like?  Do you have a mongoose schema? What are some example queries you expect to make after you insert all your data?